# Revolutionary Slider fixed height on smaller screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, revolution-slider

Change height of RS based on screen size

Below example is responsive and image height is small on small screen such as 320px width or 360px with screen.

http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.8/page_home2.html

I want to define height for smaller screen and keep it to minimum let us say 250px

`<div class="tp-banner revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive" id="revslider-192" style="height: 137px;">`

I have not found any option where i can keep the height to `min-height:250px`

I try to add class but that is override by the script when screen-size is changed.

doesn't RS have any option for height for small screens

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

CSS supports a `@media screen and (min-width: 250px){}` or a `@media screen and (max-width: 250px){}` tag.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentBS/hke51d18/) (just change the size of the result)

Whether RS has its own options, I don't know. But if you can access the files, you can add a bit of code easily :)

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it but it breaks design when another email show up next image in queue appears small and then resize to custom height.

Comment: Maybe if you get the window width and height using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. If you then calculate the proportions of your image you can adjust it using jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: I an using now window.width of jquery to check the with and according initializing the RS function. That solves problem but when i do same with window.resize this doesn't trigger function.

Comment: But why do you want to resize the window? Why don't you just make the slider and especially the images itself responsible and let them fit (in their proportions) the page width?

Comment: My images are responsive let us 1920x500 but these images look very small on small screen like 320 or 360. but are good for large screens

Comment: Well, first: Are all your images in that size?
And second: You can either cut them off at the sides or resize them in their proportions. I'm quite busy myself so I can't make an example, but when I find some time I will help you more

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using revolution slider 4. My recommendation is that you download revolution slider 5. It handles mobile in a completely new way. You can adjust appearance of your slides for mobile, tablet, notebook and wide desktop and for each of the screens you can manually adjust width and height. I tried it on couple of my new sliders and it's working perfectly. Rev5 looks completely different so you need to spend some time to learn it, but documentation is good and is worth your time.

Hope this helps